# PHP_OS - does it contain OS it was built on or runs on?

Tags: php

I searched for quite a while now, but i could not find a definite answer to the question wether the constant PHP_OS contains the OS php was built on or runs on.

The php documentation of php_uname (http://php.net/manual/de/function.php-uname.php) states:
"For the name of just the operating system, consider using the PHP_OS constant, but keep in mind this constant will contain the operating system PHP was ***built on***. "

However, on the very same page there is a comment from 2006 stating:
"Contrary to the last note, PHP_OS does display the OS PHP runs on currently, [...] This has nothing to do with the system PHP was built on."

I could not find any definite answer anywhere on the web regarding this question (topis about php_uname and PHP_OS mostly only cover os detection and similar topics). What's right now - the documentation or the comment?

The pear-core package uses PHP_OS to determine wether it's ***running*** on Unix-like systems or on windows, so is it safe to assume the documentation is indeed wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a look at the source code. The configure script does this:

```
PHP_OS=`uname | xargs`
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED(PHP_OS,"$PHP_OS",[uname output])
```

and then `main.c` does this:

```
char *php_os;
php_os=PHP_OS;
REGISTER_MAIN_STRINGL_CONSTANT("PHP_OS", php_os, strlen(php_os), CONST_PERSISTENT | CONST_CS);
```

which means that `PHP_OS` in PHP is what was in `php_os` in the C code, which is what was #defined by the header file constructed by the configure script, which is determined by running `uname` at configuration time.

So, it's the system you were built on, not the system you were running on.

There's some special-cased code for Windows: `main.c` sets `php_os` to `"WINNT"` if `WIN32` is defined. But, again, this is at build time, not at run time, even if you manage to compile on Unix and run on Windows or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, i think this answers the question.

I will let a note on php.net that the old comment seems to be wrong.

Comment: If I've answered your question to your satisfaction, you should accept the answer. (Or Jon's, if you prefer that one.)

Answer (score 3):

`PHP_OS` (the PHP constant) is a constant [defined](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_4/main/main.c#2087) when the PHP module starts up. Its value [comes](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_4/main/main.c#1960) from either the `PHP_WIN32` or `PHP_OS` C constants (following the trail finally leads to [this](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_4/configure.in#1272), but that's not necessary to answer the question).

So what it describes is the system PHP was *built* on.